# Is new Scanner(System.in) autocloseable?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
  // reads the player's lottery ticket from the console. Collect 6
  // unique numbers. Little bug here. 
  public static Set<Integer> getTicket() {
    Set<Integer> ticket = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    try (Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in)) {
      System.out.print("\nType your " + NUMBERS + " unique lotto numbers: ");
      while (ticket.size() < NUMBERS) {
        int number = console.nextInt();
        ticket.add(number);
      }
    }
    return ticket;
  }
```

Eclipse is still giving me a warning "Resource Leak: 'console is never closed'. Indeed there's no console.close(). But I had read that Scanner(System.in) is autocloseable implying to me that I should not get this warning.

So there are a few possibilities:

1. Eclipse's warning is incorrect
2. Scanner(System.in) is not autocloseable
3. Something else altogether.

Your comments are appreciated.

Comment: `Scanner` is a autocloseable, but it's a bad idea to close a `Scanner` wrapping `System.in` (because `System.in` is a global, and once closed you can't reopen it).

Comment: For that matter, though, opening a `Scanner` against `System.in` in a loop like this is begging for data loss in readahead buffers. Better to pass the `Scanner` in as a parameter.

Comment: I can't reproduce this waring. Tested on `Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Build id: 20160218-0600`

Comment: @chrylis can you explain with a code sample, not sure what you mean about passing the scanner in as a param.

Comment: @Pshemo Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) Build id: 20160218-0600 is what I have too. But it might be further dependent on the JDK version or whatnot

Comment: What do you not understand about passing parameters to methods?

Comment: @chrylis puleeze. "For that matter, though, opening a Scanner against System.in in a loop like this is begging for data loss in readahead buffers." Why does passing Scanner as a parameter address this?

Comment: You create the `Scanner` once instead of repeatedly.